# iPod Touch will charge from computer USB, but not from AC outlet

Tags: ipod-touch, usb, battery, charging

I have an iPod Touch.  If I plug it into the AC outlet, with a AC/USB power adapter, the iPod will charge to about 20%, and then stop charging.  However, if I plug it into a computer USB outlet (using the *same* USB cable), it will charge fully to 100%.

Electricity is electricity, no matter where it comes from, so why wouldn't it charge from an AC outlet?

Comment: your AC-USB is broken!

Comment: Actually, no, it's perfectly fine.  And, I have to add that I also use this same AC adapter to charge other items (including an Android tablet and my Samsung Galaxy S4), and NEVER have a problem with it.  The problem occurs ONLY with the iPod Touch.  I've also tried a different AC adapter, and the exact same thing happens.  So, the only common denominator is the iPod.

Comment: Electricity is electricity right up to the point where you look at how it's being supplied in volts and milliamp hours. Just because the charger works with other devices doesn't guarantee that _everything_ will work with it. Simple test: try another AC charger.

Comment: As you can see from my comment above, I have ALREADY tried another AC charger.  Same result.

Comment: Have you tried charging another device on the same AC charger to determine if it works?

Comment: Oh nvm you already have. Silly me 

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like your AC to USB charger is having a problem with heat.

It charges for a while (while heating up) then it stops.

If you let it cool down for a while I assume it continues charging.

In any case, I would suggest replacing it.

Comment: Actually, no, it's perfectly fine.  And, I have to add that I also use this same AC adapter to charge other items (including an Android tablet and my Samsung Galaxy S4), and NEVER have a problem with it.  The problem occurs ONLY with the iPod Touch.  I've also tried a different AC adapter, and the exact same thing happens.  So, the only common denominator is the iPod.

Comment: well now we know :) good investigating work so far.